# Автоматизация. AddEventListener. Как имитировать пользователя посредством js?

Tags: javascript, dom

Вечер добрый.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Есть форма. Она реагирует на ввод символа с клавиатуры.

В консоли появляется:

`removing listener`
`action **domain/text/text/text @**`
`POST http...`

Существует возможность с помощью js имитировать ввод пользователя?

Обычно я пользуюсь `innerText и ('#button').click()`

Но тут негде клик и нету батон

Не могу найти информации о том как манипулировать эвентлистенерами
Это вообще реально? Или мне для решения этого вопроса нужно уже отправлять **GET** запросы

Я вандал самоучка.
Буду благодарен хотябы направлению в какую сторону копать

Answer (score 0):

Здравстуйте!

Да, есть такой способ. Вам нужно использовать *element.dispatchEvent*. Например, создаёте событие KeyboardEvent, символизирующее нажатие клавиши "Enter", и отправляете его на input:

```
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {key: "Enter"}));
```